# Does PHP || or operator work with != not is equal to operator

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a question. Lately I was working with a IF condition. Suppose I have a variable `$var` which is equal to `'something'`

So here's the code:

```
if ($var != 'something' || $var != 'that') {
    // Do a dance
} else {
    // Cook something
}
```

But that doesn't work for me. But if I use it like this:

```
if ($var == 'something' || $var == 'that') {
    // Cook something
} else {
    // Do a dance
}
```

So why did my IF condition with != doesn't work?

Just wanted to know the difference so I can use it properly in future :)

Comment: depends on what you're looking for. `OR` or `AND`?

Comment: What are $var1 and $var2 when it doesn't work?

Comment: You're probably looking for `&&`, easy to get confused when negating

Comment: as stated, we don't know what your variables are, nor do we know what you're looking to match. *Try both flavours*

Comment: Have edit my question so you guys can better understand it...

Comment: *"So why did my IF condition with != doesn't work?"* - because one or both failed. you have answers below, ask them.

Answer (score 2):

Boolean algebra:

```
&& | T F    || | T F
---|----    ---|----
T  | T F     T | T T
F  | F F     F | T F
```

You have:

```
if    (($var1 != 'this') || ($var2 != 'that')) {
```

which is logically equivalent to

```
if (! (($var == 'this') && ($var2 == 'that')) )
```

if **EITHER** of your conditions evaluates to true, then the entire thing evaluates to true. The only way this could evaluate to false is if BOTH variables are equal to the those values.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you are using wrong logic operator. By [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), negation of `A OR B` is `not-A AND not-B`